# PouchDB sync cancel and restart

Tags: pouchdb

I'm establishing sync (with event listeners) on application start and I need to stop it and run again. There is a .cancel() function that works, but how I can restart the sync?

I've tried to delete object returned from sync() function after cancel() and run sync() again , but it sometimes raises a warning "pouchdb-6.1.2.min.js:7 (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.". As I get it, my old listeners are not removed by cancel().

How can I stop and start sync correctly?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong! It's just a warning to make sure you're not adding unwanted event listeners (f.e. in a loop). But you actually want them so everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how can I remove registered listeners for sync to avoid this message?

Comment: `sync.removeAllListeners()` works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct way is the following:

```
var db = new PouchDB('local');
var remoteDb = new PouchDB('URL');
var sync = db.sync(remoteDb, {live: true});
```

Whenever you want to restart sync you call the following function:

```
function restartSync() {
  sync.on('complete', () => {
    sync = db.sync(remoteDb, {live: true});
  });
  sync.cancel();
}
```

Source: [https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html#canceling—replication](https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html#canceling%E2%80%94replication)

Comment: Yes, this is how I made it finally, but I also remove all listeners.