# How to cancel one-off replication

Tags: pouchdb

Upon starting my cordova app, I do the following to sync my `remoteDb` to the local `db`:

```
db.replicate.from(remoteDb).on('complete', () => {
  // Load app with server state
}).catch(() => {
  // Load app with old state
});
```

If the database is very large and the internet connection is very slow, this can take a LONG time (e.g. 30s).

I would like to cancel this replication if the `complete` callback has not been called after 10s.

Is there a way to cancel the replication or trigger the `.catch()` callback with a

```
setTimeout(() => {...}, 10000);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PouchDB sync cancel and restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264717/pouchdb-sync-cancel-and-restart)

Comment: No, unfortunately, that only applies to live replications like `db.replicate.from(remoteDb, {live: true)`

Comment: What's the harm in using `live`?

Comment: I want to do one initial replication to get the local state to the server's and then load my app and start live syncing